# I am getting error as "operation aborted, Internet explorer can't open the page"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have created a shopping cart site, and i have got two complains for the same issue, but i am not able to track the main problem...
They say they get the message "**operation aborted, Internet explorer can't open the page**" whenever they navigate to any page, and clicking "OK" displays "page cannot be displayed".

Could someone help me out? what could be the reason behind this..

Getting this problem in IE-6,7.

> **EDIT**

I was never reported by this error before. but now I am getting this error very frequently, 
My site is live and happening, Its an osCommerce Site and i dont know where to make workaround changes in the site?

Comment: Sounds like a timeout...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encounted this problem before. It's caused by javascript. Your writing something into the DOM before the DOM has finished loading.

For example you might have something like:

```
<script>document.write('hello world');</script>
```

When it should be like

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'hello world'; 
}  
</script>
```

Comment: So u mean to say that this error must coming on the page load?

Comment: What I'm saying is that javascript is trying to modify the page before onload

Comment: I found it really usefull thanks , But why dont I find this issue in my testserver and local PC, while I have same code on all the three servers, The localhost, my test server and live one?

Comment: The reason why you're not getting the same result on all servers is because of the connection/download time. Even though it might only be a few more ms, this would effect the execution of the js enough to present this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Are you [trying to modify the DOM before the page has fully loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/what-happened-to-operation-aborted)?

Comment: I ran into this, has something to do with some parent element not being closed before manipulating it, you've got to close the tag first or something, it was a while ago.

Comment: I found it really usefull thanks , But why dont I find this issue in my testserver and local PC, while I have same code on all the three servers, The localhost, my test server and live one?

Comment: My guess is that your browser loads the page so fast that the DOM becomes fully loaded before the script runs. This is especially true if you load the page from localhost.

Comment: FWIW, there are local proxies like Fiddler that can simulate slow connections: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this a few times.

First time it had to do with manipulating elements before they were closed (as others have mentioned.)

Second time the server had images in a directory that wasn't readable by "everyone" so we had to change the permissions.

Comment: I found it really usefull thanks , But why dont I find this issue in my testserver and local PC, while I have same code on all the three servers, The localhost, my test server and live one?

Comment: That is the great mystery!  Same here, worked in some places, busted in others.